# Modifying a Mutex<Option<>>

Tags: rust

I have a quick stylistic or idiomatic question about `Mutex`.

Is there a more elegant way to modify the data in `fn upper()` than using `*string = match *string`. It seems odd to dereference on both side, but if I don't, I don't know how to handle the `<MutexGuard>` part of string.

Link to [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=77ba93584f224e799b51&version=stable)

```
use std::sync::{Mutex};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SharedFile{
    file: Mutex<Option<String>>
}

impl SharedFile{
    fn new()-> SharedFile{
       SharedFile{
           file: Mutex::new(Some("test".to_owned())),
           //file: Mutex::new(None),
       }
    }

    fn upper(&self){
      let mut string  = self.file.lock().unwrap();

      *string= match *string{
         Some(ref mut x) => Some(x.to_uppercase()),
         None => Some("Empty".to_owned()),
      };

      println!("{:?}", *string);
    }
}

fn main() {
        let shared = SharedFile::new();
        shared.upper();
        println!("{:?}", shared);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, there is:

```
*string = string.as_ref()
    .map(|x| x.to_uppercase())
    .unwrap_or_else(|| "Empty".to_owned())
```

This in fact is not specific to `Mutex`; the same problem and solution apply to `&mut Option<String>`, for example. That said, the solution with `*string = match *string { ... }` is absolutely fine as well. BTW, you don't need `mut` in `Some(ref mut x)`, just `Some(ref x)` is fine - `to_uppercase()` only needs a shared reference to the string.